# Update part of timestamp field

Tags: mysql, update

I'm trying to fix a glitch in one of my tables.  Several hundred records were given the wrong timestamp.  The times are correct, but the date is wrong.
I could write a little java program to fix it, but I'd much rather learn how to do it via the command line.

What sort of update could I use to fix JUST the date part of timeout and timein?

The query results for the table showing the incorrect date on timeout and timein:

```
mysql> select id, fauteam, timeout, timein from fauactivity limit 5;
+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | fauteam | timeout             | timein              |
+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |       1 | 2015-10-14 08:18:50 | 2015-10-14 08:19:32 |
|  2 |       1 | 2015-10-14 08:20:39 | 2015-10-14 08:31:13 |
|  3 |       1 | 2015-10-14 08:31:58 | 2015-10-14 09:01:29 |
|  4 |       1 | 2015-10-14 09:02:52 | 2015-10-14 09:03:23 |
|  5 |       1 | 2015-10-14 09:04:27 | 2015-10-14 09:06:49 |
+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: You could use DATE_ADD(timeout,INTERVAL -1 DAY), as @dnoeth wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add or subtract a number of days, e.g.:

```
update fauactivity
set timeout = timeout - interval 1 day,
    timein = timein - interval 1 day
where ...
```

Comment: It didn't even occur to me to think in terms of dates. I was thinking in terms of strings.  Thanks!